# Android: How to: display image from sdcard?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: Display Image from SD CARD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725718/android-display-image-from-sd-card)

Here's my current code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.LayoutParams;

public class DisplayImageMapActivity extends Activity {
    ImageView iv;
    private final String FLOOR = "F";
    private final String storagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/AppH23";
    private final String localMapsPath = storagePath + "/localMaps";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.storageimage);

        RadioGroup levelRGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.level_rgroup);

        int levelSize = 8;
        for (int i = 0; i < levelSize; i++) {
            RadioButton levelRButton = new RadioButton(this);
            if(i==0) {
                levelRButton.setText(new StringBuffer(i+1).append(FLOOR).append("(start)"));
            } else if (i==7) {
                levelRButton.setText(new StringBuffer(i+1).append(FLOOR).append("(end)"));
            }
            levelRButton.setTag((i+1) + FLOOR);
            levelRButton.setLayoutParams(
                    new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));

            levelRGroup.addView(levelRButton);
        }

        levelRGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, final int checkedId) {
                iv.setImageURI(Uri.parse(new StringBuffer(localMapsPath)
                .append("/").append(group.findViewById(checkedId).getTag()).append(".gif").toString()));
                iv.invalidate();
            }
        });

        levelRGroup.getChildAt(0).performClick();

    }
}
```

Here's my environment:
a) 2.1-update1

It kinda strange, my image from /sdcard/AppH23/localMaps/???.gif doesn't show.
all gif files are confirmed that are existing.

**UPDATE:**
here's my previous post and you may confirm that the gif image was displayed a while ago. [gif image displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7306069/android-how-to-display-an-image-file-buildings-floor-map-and-update-the-file)

Comment: ` new RadioButton(this);` creating objects like this will lead to memory leak! [see](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)

Comment: i tried that code a while ago, then I successfully displayed the image. But now, kinda weird. @CapDroid No any error.

Comment: @Vikas memory leak? what should I do?

Comment: oohhh even I removed the RadioGroup and RadioButtons. Just leaving the ImageView. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to make `levelRGroup` a class variable(similar to `iv`). It is currently a local variable and it will be garbage collected at some point after `onCreate` returns. When it will be deleted cannot be known and that would cause inconsistent behaviour even if you do not change anything in your code.